# Evaluating $\int_{0}^{\pi} \left(\sin x\right)^x dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

Can we evaluate this Integral by using Integration Techniques or maybe Series Expansion?
$$I = \int_{0}^{\pi} \left(\sin x\right)^x dx$$
Obviously, the answer from any Integrating Calculator is $2.0187168552$, but I'm wondering how to reach so.

Comment: It is unlikely to have a closed form.

Comment: maybe by approximating the integral with its Riemann sum.